# Controlling omxplayer with frontend-term

Tags: omxplayer

I use the omxplayer-console along with frontend-term. Together they offer a crude gui in a terminal window while I am SSHed into my Pi.  This used to work well for me and offered a number of keystrokes from which I could skip forward, skip backward, pause and resume and a few other things from keyboard at the terminal.

I haven't used it in a while and when I tried again tonight, I can't seem to do anything to get it to recognize my keystrokes.  Running the frontend-term program by itself I can see that the keystrokes echo the commands to the console:

```
P: pause
f: seek +30
F: seek +600
   etc...
```

But piping it to the console does not seem to give me the controls I used to have.

```
frontend-term | omxplayer-console /path/to/my/media
```

**Does anyone know what I can do to return the functioning controls?**

EDIT:
A couple of weeks ago I thought the problem to be related to permissions on an intermediate io file.  It seemed that when I switched to sudo I had complete control of everything and that the omxplayer-console directory was set to root ownership. So the solution seemed to be:

```
sudo chown pi. omxplayer-console -R
```

Where omxplayer-console is the the directory where the programs reside.

But that is NOT the reason. Once again I have lost control and the rights are exactly as I set them a few weeks ago. SO what ELSE did I do a couple of weeks ago that I need to do again? Anybody have any ideas?